# When I switch to a tab that was inactive, I see inbox and achievements boxes "flashing through" the accumulated history

Tags: bug, notifications, global-inbox, top-bar

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open one tab with SE site;
2. Open another tab with SE site. The first tab goes hibernating as inactive;
3. Do something in the second tab, receive votes, answers, click on inbox or achievements boxes (to reset red and green counters).
4. Switch to the first tab;

Expected to see:

Just gray inbox and gray chart, showing no new events (unless there was one while I was switching tabs);

What happens:

I see both inbox and chart becoming activated. Then gray again. Then activated again and so on until the incoming events drained. Finally (after about a second) it settles on the correct indication.

Comment: While a bug this sounds awesome